# Data source name not found and no default driver specified - Zabbix

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, zabbix

I am trying to monitor an MSSQL database via ODBC with Zabbix, but I was getting an error that my DSN is invalid, even after performing several tests, does anyone have any idea what it could be?

/etc/freetds.conf

```
[MSSQL_SERVER]
    host = <ip>
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description= FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL
Setup= /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
UsageCount=1
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[MSSQL]
Driver = FreeTDS
Servername = MSSQL_SERVER
```

isql DSN

```
[root@zabbix]# isql MSSQL sa <password>
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> quit
```

tsql Servername

```
[root@zabbix]# tsql -S MSSQL_SERVER -U sa -P <password>
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> quit
```

tsql conf

```
[root@zabbix]# tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v1.1.20
             freetds.conf directory: /etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: auto
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
                            OpenSSL: no
                             GnuTLS: yes
                               MARS: yes
```

Error: `Cannot connect to ODBC DSN: [SQL_ERROR]:[IM002][0][[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified]`

Template:

[image]

Comment: What's `tds version = 8.0`? SQL Server 2019 uses [the latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/135d0ebe-5c4c-4a94-99bf-1811eccb9f4a), which is 7.4.

Comment: I use container, https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/

Comment: My zabbix server and proxy are also containers, could this be the problem?

Comment: I don't think this would be the problem, but... [microsoft/mssql-server-linux](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) has been deprecated for about 2 years now, you might want to try one of its replacements at [Microsoft SQL Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

Comment: Since the checks are executed on the Zabbix proxy and the results forwarded to the Zabbix server, have you been doing your ODBC configuration and testing on the server or on the proxy?

Comment: I did a test, installed the zabbix server localhost, and it worked, it looks like the zabbix docker image, does not compile the odbc libs, even with the -v parameter